# How to use *args when i only have 1 string?

Tags: python, positional-argument

So lets say i have a python function like this:

```
def function_name(*param1, param2):
   ...
```

And i have a string "120,220,400". Is there a way i can place it in param1 without transforming it to a tuple of lists/other tuples? i tried using .split(',') but i just end up having ["120","220","400"].

I still want to use *param1 and dont really want to change the function, i am just developing a ui where the value read in the label comes out with a string "120,220,400"

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with keyword arguments. `param2` is keyword-only, but the question is about `param1`.

Comment: I changed some things

Comment: You should be able to call the function just fine with that string.  `function_name("120,220,400", param2=whatever)`  What is the difficulty?

Comment: I would only have a tuple with "120,220,400". I should have ("120","220","400")

Comment: Oh, you want the numbers passed as separate elements inside `param1`?  You didn't say that.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Because now that i made an user interface i can no longer have "150","400", ... as an input. Only everything packed up together with a string... I was hoping there was a solution to this besides changing the function input type

Comment: @Scipio You don't have to change the function input type, but I would question whether or not packing all of the positional arguments is the correct approach to begin with.  Without seeing the actual function and its purpose, that is indeterminable.  Another consideration is that instead, maybe the function getting the user input from your UI is not correct.  If these are expected to interact then the data structure returned by the UI and the input expected by the function should be designed to match each other without needing the extra `.split()` call

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable `my_var = "120,220,400"`, you can call your function like so:

```
function_name(*my_var.split(','), param2=whatever)
```

The `*` unpacks the list returned by `str.split` into different parameters, which then get packed back up into a single tuple.

Comment: When i call the function like that i get an invalid syntax error

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: I am using verison 3.11

Comment: Then this syntax should definitely be legal. Please update your question so we have a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).